# Loading ddl in python goes in Windows Error 0xE0434F4D

Tags: python, windows, dll

I have a motherboard with a kinda of jamma connector, model is axiomtek GMB121.
They provide library for GPIO for windows  as dll. The win32 application example works fine.

I'm trying to comunicate with this ddl using python.
I wrote so far, coping from the C code example and converting in python:

```
from ctypes import *

ERR_Success = 0
ERR_Error = -1
ERR_NotExist = -2
ERR_Opened = -3
ERR_NotOpened = -4
debounce=1
mydll = windll.LoadLibrary("C:\\Users\\test\\Documents\\TestPy\\AGP1_MFC64.dll")

iRet=mydll.AXGMB_Nvram_Open()
if (iRet != ERR_Success and iRet != ERR_Opened):
    print "error"
iRet = mydll.AXGMB_DIO_SetDebounceTime(debounce)
if (iRet == ERR_Success):
    print "AXGMB_DIO_SetDebounceTime Function success"
else:
    print "AXGMB_DIO_SetDebounceTime Function failure"
mydll.AXGMB_DIO_Close()
```

But what I got is:

> iRet=mydll.AXGMB_Nvram_Open()
>
> WindowsError: [Error -532459699] Windows Error 0xE0434F4D

And I don't know how to proceed, any advice?

Comment: So, the faulty line is `iRet=mydll.AXGMB_Nvram_Open()` and it raises an exception (program stops)? Could you share the header file that came with the *.dll*?

Comment: Apparently, that *.dll* is invoking some *COM* that fails. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eccd7901-caac-4d3a-8614-7b743f83dec6/error-code-0xe0434f4d?forum=csharpgeneral, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/13522611-8bad-4bd0-bd0d-dec983abfac0/dtutil-error-code-532459699?forum=sqlintegrationservices.